# React Redux setup returns a function rather than the value

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm setting up redux for the first time and I have a little bit of a problem getting my reducers value;

I have an user reducer that return a initial state.

```
export default (state={}, action) => {
    return state;
}
```

Now this should return an empty object.

In here i'm import the user

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

// Reducers
import user from './userReducer'

console.log(user)

export default combineReducers({
    user
})
```

The problem is that in the console.log(user) I don't get the empty object. I get this.

```
ƒ () {
var state = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : {};
var action = arguments[1];

return state;
}
```

I'm using redux for the first time so any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console.log output is correct. Your `user` import imports a function, not an object:

```
// This is a function
export default (state={}, action) => {
    return state;
}
```

What you see in the output is an ES5 transpiled version of your function.